# XSS Protection in Express Apps

Tags: node.js, angularjs, oauth-2.0, xss, sanitization

I am developing an express app which serves as a REST api with web client and may be future mobile clients. I am using a Oauth 2.0 token authentication for both clients. This gives a good deal of security against CSRF. I want to know **How to provide security against XSS**.

*I made the tokens validity period very less, requiring the client to request with refresh_tokens and other client details for access_tokens. This makes it a bit safe but not entirely*.

I am concerned with the with **client_id and client_secret being stolen** since its present in the front-end javascript code and it being used by other client to validate. *I am thinking of using a **JWT for the client authentication**, will this be helpful?*

Data Sanitisation is another which I am confused about. There are modules like [validator](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js), [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) which give regex validation. According to this [blog post](http://cosmicrealms.com/blog/2014/02/07/benchmark-of-node-dot-js-json-validation-modules-part-2/) JSON Schema validations are fast. In the REST Api JSON will used for data exchange so I was wandering why can't I use modules like **[tv4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4) or any other JSON Schema validators for data validations??** I am not asking for suggestions to use what, I just want to know the *basic difference in the kind of validations each provide and specially from a point of view of XSS protection and sanitisation*.

Comment: Why are you exposing the client secret to the browser? It should be kept on the server only.

Comment: If it is kept only in the server....How will the client sent it to the server for the server to verify whether this client should be allowed to interact or not?

Comment: If by client secret, you mean the OAuth client secret, then any user accessing your site can steal that secret. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I don't want that...thats why I am asking where I do store it?

Comment: The classic OAuth scenario is this:
1. User access site X which uses OAuth at site Y
2. User's browser is redirected to Y to sign in/approve
3. After approval user's browser is redirected back to X with a code
4. Site X server uses that code together with client secret to obtain an access token (and possibly also an id_token)
5. Site X server passes the access_token to the browser (possibly after validating the id_token)

So the request to obtain the token is back-channel. And thus only the server knows.

Comment: In this case both the client and server are handled by me only. If you read my question you would be able to understand that the server is a REST Api and the client is an angular.js app. So now for the client to send requests to the server, it has to send the client secret. Now where do I store it.

Comment: Ok. Now I am confused. I guess you are using OAuth because of your future mobile clients. But how will the user authenticate? OAuth provides a token for an authenticated user. It's an authorization protocol, not authentication. The best fit for your application would be OAuth2 Client Credentials Grant (see the spec), but you still need a unique username/password per user. But you don't need a client secret.

Comment: So you are saying that I implement a Client Credentials Grant which verifies the client and then it allows the client to interact with the Api but with scope for (lets say) only login request and when the user submits the username, password and is verified then its gets scope to interact with the rest Api.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant.

Comment: 1. If you are afraid of user credentials being stolen, you can try Dynamic token of CSRF. That way the token is updated every time any interaction happens between server and client. It prevents use of older tokens and simultaneous use from multiple clients.  2. Modules like validator will check for specific harmful script tags, which is required for preventing XSS. Module like TV4 can also help if you provide it the proper schema. I use TV4 for validating my JSON object.

Answer (score 2):

So you have three separate questions here:

**1) How to protect against XSS:** As long as you use JSON to share data between the client & server and use standard libraries/methods for encoding/decoding JSON, you are mostly protected. After this, you only need to worry about DOM Based XSS, which is harder to be protected. But basically you need to be careful for not using any user supplied input that can be interpreted as anything other than "string" you intended. (please visit https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS for more information)

**2) client_id and client_secret being stolen:** This does not seem to be possible in the way you require. In your scenario (where you distribute clientid&secret in javascript code) there is no way on server side to know whether the request is coming from your client or a fake one.

**3) Data Sanitisation:** I see two levels of sanitisation in the libraries you & blogpost mentioned. validator or express-validator is mostly used to validate individual data fields. Whereas others can validate a JSON object structure in addition to what "validator" does. If you require all exchanged data is in JSON format (as suggested for XSS protection as well) then you can use json object validators like tv4. (the only drawback of tv4 seems to be allowing latest json spec, which should not be a problem for you)

BTW: It would be easier if you specified your client application is purely client-side javascript (angularjs). I could not understand your question until I found this info in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed Restful Authentication System same as your case with NodeJS, MongoDB, ExpressJS in order to provide flexible authentication system for multiple clients like web, mobile. Let me summarize you the important points.

I have used html5 localstorage to keep user token after first time login by using login form. When user click login button, username and password sent to server and validated. After successfull validation, unique access token sent to client and stroed in local sotrage. If you have vulnerability on your client application, anyone can get your access token and make request by using your token. In order to prevent this, you need to use ssl connection for your app. This problem does not exists only restful auth systems, this can be happen in server side session storage. Let me explain this. I am using PHP for session. When user logs in, user session saved in to temp file on server and that session id sent to client browser. Somehow, if I can get that id, I can make request with header that contains someone's session id. When you compare, restful auth seems more flexible to me. I suggest you to ;

1. Use SSL connection prevent your access_token from to be stolen
2. Generate access token with powerfull encryption methods(SHA-256)
3. Small expire time for access_token the better
4. Implement a middleware for token validation for backend service usage. I mean make your requests like;

   /use/update/{userid}

with custom headers contains your user token.

1. Design 5 attempt failed system for your backend. If user cannot success at 5 time try, this means someone tries to send random tokens in order to get in to system. Detect and block that IP
2. You can also deny requests other than browser clients.

Those are the informations that I have learnt while implementing the project.

Comment: How do I make sure that only browser client from my app and mobile clients can connect and not others

Comment: It is not problem. Only check the token if valid or not. If token valid, then user pass. As best practice, you can deny clients that has headers different that, mobile or web browser. You can disallow those clients in web server level. So, You can protect yourself from making vaidation for invalid clients. For example, I am doing such aprotection, because I don't want some crawlers like baidu(chinese crawler) to crawl my site. I deny them by checking headers